# Using linq to instantiate objects containing lists of other objects, where query criteria is on inner list

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have a DB table, let's call it 'People', with an Entity associated with it, and a view model class, Person, that contains a list of objects from another table, let's say 'Jobs'. Each job has a length of time held. Using LINQ, I want to make an IQueryable that contains an IQueryable.

The database has a lot of people in it. I want to pull the people whom have had a job longer than 6 months.

What I have is this:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople() =>
    Repo<Person>.Get().Select(p => new Person 
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Jobs = GetJobs(p.Name)
    }).Where(h => h.Jobs.Count() > 0);

public IQueryable<Job> GetJobs(string name) => 
    Repo<Job>.Get().Where(j => j.name == name && j.time > 6);
```

The problem is that this pulls every person, then queries for jobs for each of them, which is inefficient. Is there a good way of pulling jobs first, then creating a list of people, each with their own list of qualifying jobs?

Comment: Why are People and Jobs in two different Repositories?

Comment: Apologies. They are not.

Comment: @RobertMcKee actually, the repos are slightly different. They're both the same interface, but with different models. I edited to show that.

Comment: Isn't GetPeople going to give you a list of all jobs for all people for each person the way you currently have it?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. This is a simplified version of the real thing. I'll edit again.

Comment: The reason I need this to be faster is that Person actually has two lists, one of which is Jobs, and Jobs has 4 lists of objects, and one of those lists has a list as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would say you would just do this, if using Entity Frameworks:

```
var results=db.People.Where(p=>p.Jobs.Any(j=>j.time>6));
```

This assumes you have a `Person` class, that is represented by the table `People`, and the `Person` class has a navigation property called `Jobs` that references the `Jobs` table.